# Remove null value only if it is at the beginning of an array in Java

Tags: java, arrays

I have an `Object` array and I would like to code a method that removes the null values of the array only if they are at the beginning of it. That means it's irrelevant if a null value exists in the middle of the array.
Is this heading in the right direction?

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    if (array[i] == null && array[i+1] != null){}
```

Comment: It’s probably i bit more complicated than needed. If I understand your requirements correctly, I’d iterate over any nulls to find the first non-null and then (if not at index 0) move the remaining contents left and either adjust the top/size accordingly or fill out with nulls at the back/end/right.

Comment: How are you keeping track of the number of elements in the array? A count? Asking because an array has a fixed size.

Comment: So you suggest i use an iteration to mark the indexes of the null values and only if one of them is at array[0] copy the array without it?

Comment: I think the suggestion was to iterate until you find the first non null and save that index. Then, if index != 0, iterate again and set all objects back by that many positions. Fill the rest with null.

Comment: Hello @konoshef, welcome on StackOverflow! Please read this article on how to ask questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### [`Arrays#copyOfRange`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOfRange(T%5B%5D,%20int,%20int))

Count the `null` elements in the beginning and use `Arrays#copyOfRange` to get an array out the original array from the index, `count` till the last index.

**Demo:**

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] original = { null, null, null, "Hello", "World", null, null, "Hi", "Bye" };

        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < original.length && original[i] == null; i++)
            count++;

        String[] result = Arrays.copyOfRange(original, count, original.length);

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
[Hello, World, null, null, Hi, Bye]
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to loop trough the whole array to check if the first item in array is null

Something like this would make more sense to me:

```
while (array.length > 0 && array[0] == null) {
    //Remove the value
}
```

Comment: Removing the first object in an array is O(n) since you need to shift all the remaining objects. This approach will be inefficient. This looks like O(n^2).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using java 9 or higher, something like below might be what you are looking for (Using a string array as example):

```
String[] myArray = {null, null, "foo", "bar", null, "baz"};
String[] noLeadingNulls = Arrays.stream(myArray)
                                .dropWhile(Objects::isNull)
                                .toArray(String[]::new);

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(noLeadingNulls));

//[foo, bar, null, baz]
```

Answer (score 0):

Find the first non null element. Then move all elements from that position back to position 0. Fill the end with null.

Here is a primitive for-loop based solution that does exactly 1 pass over the array:

```
private void trim() {
    int first;
    //noinspection StatementWithEmptyBody
    for(first = 0; first < array.length && array[first] == null; ++first); // Find index of first non null;
    if(first == 0 || first == array.length - 1) {
        // Break if first is non null or if there are only null objects
        return;
    }
    // Start at 0 and move elements back, ending when all elements have been moved
    for(int i = 0; i + first < array.length; ++i) {
        array[i] = array[i + first];
    }
    // Fill the tail with null
    for(int i = array.length - first; i < array.length; ++i){
        array[i] = null;
    }
}
```

Test and test output:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(trimArray.getArray()));
trimArray.trim();
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(trimArray.getArray()));
```

```
[null, null, null, null, null, null, null, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, null, 14, null, null, 17, 18, 19]
[7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, null, 14, null, null, 17, 18, 19, null, null, null, null, null, null, null]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Object lastArrayIndex = array[0];
if (lastArrayIndex == null) ArrayUtils.remove(array, 0);
```